# PHP Warning: Module 'xxxxxxx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 written repeatedly into error_log

Tags: php

I am using a webhost (webhotelli.fi) to host my website. I do not have access to the actual server. Only a few settings in cpanel, so I cannot configure things like on my own server. Last week, I noticed my website was using loads of more space than I actually have there. I noticed the error_log files was 1.6 GIGAGBYTES in size. I deleted it to start it from scratch.

what happens is, this whole block down here in the code gets written into the error_log ad inifitum, causing it to grown several megabytes every day.

I have asked the webhost for help, they have attempted something but it is not fixed yet. The last thing they adviced mw to switch the PHP version from 7.2 to 7.4 on my site. I did that, but it did nothing.

Has anyone encountered this, and have a way to fix it? As I said, there is nothing I personally can do in my site or code, since it is all connected to the actual server. I do not even reference any of those modules medntioned in the error_log in my code.

```
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jul-2020 19:13:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem locally (and this was the #1 search result), I keep seeing:

> Warning: Module "imap" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

So I searched my PhpInfo for mentions of IMAP.

```
php -r "echo phpinfo();" | grep imap
```

And I see two "Additional .ini files parsed":

```
PHP Warning:  Module "imap" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Module "imap" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Additional .ini files parsed => /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/imap.ini
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, gophers, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
imap
imap.enable_insecure_rsh => Off => Off
```

I took a look at them both:

```
nano /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/20-imap.ini
```

```
nano /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/imap.ini
```

And when I saw they were both the same **I renamed one so it is not loaded**.

```
mv /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/20-imap.ini /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/20-imap.ini.duplicate.old
```